# Php strpos does not work correctly when searching a file

Tags: php

I have a php file that will search all the files on my server for any files that contains a string. If i hard code the search term in the strpos() it works fine.  but if i try to use a $string it wont work

```
works:
$file = file_get_contents($dir);
if(strpos($file,  'find me')) 

does not work:
$findme='find me';
$file = file_get_contents($dir);
if(strpos($file,  $findme))
```

any ideas?

edit:  if(strpos($file, 'find me') !== false)   does not make it work.

resolved: find me must be in tics
if(strpos($file ,  '$findme'))

Comment: How about checking for `if(strpos($file,$findme) !== false)` as a 0-index match will result in a false. (Note the [warning in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues))

Comment: i did try that, i also tried !strpos()   it seems that the $file and $findme are not being both treated as strings, i am having a similar problem in another area with str_replace that wont work unless I hardcode the replace term

Comment: Have you ever visited the [PHP's docs on this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)? There is a fine huge red flagged warning right on the return type.

Comment: @Johnny: while probably not related to the current problem, you should use Brad's form of checking to prevent other problems in future. Now, what does `var_dump($findme);` show?

Comment: var_dump echos
NULL
NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
NULL NULL
NULL NULL NULL

Comment: @Johnny: then you have your problem: `$findme` is not set, so you have a coding problem elsewhere. Do use the `!== false` method, but that isn't the current problem.

Answer (score 2):

you should be testing `if(strpos($file,  'find me') !== false)`, because `strpos($file,  'find me')` could be 0 if the file starts with "find me"

Answer (score -1):

Well, the first thing that leaps out at me is that you're using `strpos` incorrectly; you need to do `if(strpos($file, 'find me') !== false)` and `if(strpos($file, $findme) !== false)`.

Answer (score -1):

The [warning in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues) mention you should look for an explicit `false` and not just place the function in a condition. Because `strpos` could potentially return `0` or `""` (which both evaluate to false) the condition itself could fail.

Try the following instead:

```
if(strpos($file,$findme) !== false)
```

**Also,** if you're saying you've tried this and it's still failing, try running a `var_dump($file)` to make sure the haystack does indeed contain information that can be searched through.

Comment: I know for sure it contains the string because the script also searches itself and it will be listed as one of the results.   when i use $findme, there are no results at all

Comment: @johnnyCraig: Something is fishy about either `$file` or `$findme`, as (under normal conditions) the statement executes perfectly.

Comment: Not the problem, it is clearly in `$findme` (after all, the search is the one that varies, not the haystack).